# How to make pseudo 3D or 2.5D effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2.5d

After using Unity for over a year now for creating 3D games I'd like to do my first pseudo 3D or 2.5D game (or whatever it's called). What I mean is games like Clash of Clans or Boom Beach where objects are really 2D images rendered to give 3D feeling. Because I don't even know the correct word for that type of games it's really hard to get started. What I can think of is giving Camera rotation of (45, -45, 0) so that it looks down at the ground from the upper right corner and then creating empty gameObjects with Sprite Renderers and setting their rotation to (22.5, -45, 0) so that they face the camera. I don't know if that's how it's really done so could somebody give me a link to some neat tutorial or something because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you are looking for is **isometric projection.**

You can use Unity to create that effect with 3D graphics. You need to set the camera rotation to (45, -45, 0) and set the `Camera Projection` to `Orthographic`.

If you want to only use 2D graphics then the graphics are made in such a way that they are drawn in an angle that it looks like you are looking at them in 45 degrees.

If you search for **isometric unity** then you should find a ton of tutorials for Unity.